# How to access a frame inside a movieclip from within another movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip

I have a problem regarding movieclips...

On my main timeline there are 2 MCs and inside MC1 there is a button, which - when clicked - should get me to Frame 10 of MC2 (on the main timeline)...

My button code (inside mc1):

```
btn_standard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, standard_click);

function standard_click(myNextEvent:MouseEvent):void { 
    MovieClip(root).mc2.gotoAndPlay(10);
}
```

There is no error, but however the button won't work...
Can anyone please help me! :-(

EDIT:  Here's a [sample file](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10573133/flash_as3_problem.zip.html) - same problem!

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try to change gotoAndPlay to gotoAndStop. If this doesn't help can you attach FLA?

Comment: neither play nor stop will work... :-/ 
I added a quick sample .fla to my question to visualize my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add as3 code on main timeline instead of inside of mc1, like this:

```
mc1.btn_standard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, standard_click);

function standard_click(myNextEvent:MouseEvent):void { 
    mc2.gotoAndPlay(10);
}
```

Comment: didn't work either... mc2.gotoAndPlay(10) only works if mc1 and mc2 are both on the same frame - but i need them on different frames...

Comment: Then I suppose that you added MovieClips and their tweens by hand to main timeline. That's not very smart if you want to do anything more than simple animations. Add those  MovieClips by code and it will be easier for you to manipulate with it.

Answer (score 0):

This code wont work because in the 1-st frame there is no mc2:

```
function standard_click(myNextEvent:MouseEvent):void { 
    MovieClip(root).mc2.gotoAndStop(10);
}
```

Dispatch any event from this MovieClip after mouse click:

```
function standard_click(myNextEvent:MouseEvent):void { 
    dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
}
```

Add next code to the first frame of the main timeline:

```
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

mc1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
    gotoAndStop(10);
    mc2.gotoAndStop(10);
}
```